# Objeto não pode ser convertido de DBNull em outros tipos = Entity Framework Core para firebird

Tags: c#

Estou com a seguinte tabela que tem os
campos(ID, numeronota, clienteID, dataemissao, totalnota, desconto, troco).

Nessa tabela tem campos que fica nulo, exemplo o troco e desconto, eu estou querendo buscar essa tabela usando o EF Core.
Na entidade esta assim:

```
[key]  
[Colunm("ID")]  
public int ID {get; set;}  
[Colunm("NUMERONOTA")]  
public int Numeronota{get;set}  
[ForeignKey("ID")]  
public Cliente ClienteID{get; set;}  
[Colunm("DATAEMISSAO")]  
public DateTime Dataemissao{get;set;}  
[Colunm("TOTALNOTA")]  
public double Totalnota{get;set;}  
[Colunm("DESCONTO")]  
public double? Desconto{get;set;}  
[Colunm("TROCO")]  
public double? Troco{get; set;}
```

---

Na classe Context

```
public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }  
public DbSet<Nota> Notas { get; set; }
```

---

estou chamando assim

```
using ( var contexto = new EntidadesContext()) {  
                contexto.LogSQLToConsole();                  
                foreach (var nota in contexto.Nota )  
                {                    

                }  
            }
```

Se eu busco a tabela cliente que esta com todos os campos preenchidos vem normal, somente a tabela nota da o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa declarar as propriedades que podem receber valores nulos na sua entidade, assim como fez com alguns deles. E precisa verificar a mesma coisa na tabela e na entidade Cliente.

```
[key]  
[Colunm("ID")]  
public int ID {get; set;}  
[Colunm("NUMERONOTA")]  
public int? Numeronota{get;set}  
[ForeignKey("ID")]  
public Cliente ClienteID{get; set;}  
[Colunm("DATAEMISSAO")]  
public DateTime? Dataemissao{get;set;}  
[Colunm("TOTALNOTA")]  
public double? Totalnota{get;set;}  
[Colunm("DESCONTO")]  
public double? Desconto{get;set;}  
[Colunm("TROCO")]  
public double? Troco{get; set;}
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder, então eu fiz isso, mas mesmo assim o erro continua, não consegue puxar os campos que estão nullos no banco, usando SQL puro eu consigo fazer a pesquisa usando o isDBNull, mas com Entity Framework não sei fazer isso ainda.

Comment: Você revisou a classe cliente também?

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu tive que colocar todos os campos de todas as entidades como ?, 
agora passou.